# Cannot turn on bitlocker windows 7 with TPM and NTFS - Optiplex 7010

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, bitlocker, dell-optiplex

My specs are:

- Dell Optiplex 7010
- Windows  7 ultimate
- C and D drive both of them are NTFS
- TPM

My problem is:

When I am trying to activate bitlocker on drive C, I am getting error message that drives should be NTFS. Also the option to  activate Bitlocker to go is not working/available.
Any ideas how fix this?

See screen shots:

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Add more details or take a screenshot.

Comment: Open your "Disk Management" (just type it in search of start menu and click on "create and format hard disk partitions") then take another screenshot from there.

Comment: here it is:[link](https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D16254_83054272_6511759) https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D16254_83054272_6511759